# Calling type classes by using the type from a variable

Tags: scala

I have type classes depending on 2 types and one of the type contains the other

```
sealed trait Version
case class Version1() extends Version
case class Version2() extends Version

case class MyModel1(msg: String, version: Version)
case class MyModel2(msg: String, version: Version)

trait Validate[M, V] {
  def run : Boolean
}

object Validators {
  implicit object ValidateModel1 extends Validate[MyModel1, Version1] {
    override def run: Boolean = true
  }
  implicit object ValidateModel2 extends Validate[MyModel1, Version2] {
    override def run: Boolean = true
  }
}
```

And I would like to call my type classes this way:

```
object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val model = MyModel1("Test", Version1())
    validate(model)
  }

  def validate(model: MyModel1) {
    import Validators._    

    val v = implicitly[Validate[MyModel1, model.version.type]]
    v.run
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work.

> Error:(34, 23) could not find implicit value for parameter e:
>   com.playground.Validate[com.playground.MyModel1,model.version.type]
>       val v = implicitly[Validate[MyModel1, model.version.type]] Error:(34, 23) not enough arguments for method implicitly: (implicit
>   e:
>   com.playground.Validate[com.playground.MyModel1,model.version.type])com.playground.Validate[com.playground.MyModel1,model.version.type].
>   Unspecified value parameter e.
>       val v = implicitly[Validate[MyModel1, model.version.type]]

Replacing the `model.version.type` with `Version1` works

Any idea how to call my type class by pointing to the `Version` type from the `MyModel1` ?

Feel free to suggest a more explicit title :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that implicits are resolved at compile time so that the compiler cannot know whether inside

```
case class MyModel1(msg: String, version: Version)
```

version is of type `Version1` or `Version2`. It is just not known. If you need to use that information you need to keep it in the signature of your class, either through a **generic parameter** or an **abstract type** (which you will use through an helper type that will turn into a generic, so you can use it in signature and express type-relationships)

So the solution is to generify the Model like so

```
case class MyModel1[V<:Version](msg:String, version:V)
```

Comment: I have included the import in my test but not in the snippet. Thanks

Comment: Oh I totally misunderstood the question. Why are you using model.version.type ? It is a singleton type associated to the field version, are you sure that's what you meant?

Comment: It' s something I tried. I thought it returns the type of the version attribute from `MyModel`  . Do you know how I can get the correct type?